# Chrome Dev tool coverage tab for minified css

Tags: html, css, performance, google-chrome-devtools, web-performance

I want to know if there is any way to see the used and unused css from coverage tab even if our css is minified.

For example:
[For this link](https://defer-css-optimized.glitch.me/)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZDZ4.png)
you can see in coverage tab for css in source we can see green and red for used and unused css receptively line by line.

but for other site which is using minified version of css in their sites, the coverage tab shows the css in one line even if we use {} this option it only beautifies the css.

Ex -
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nansz.png)
[See this site](https://shop.valueresearchonline.com/magazines-books/wi/wealth-insight/)

Here you can see the css is in one line, and showing hyphen before every line. So in this case we can't analyse the used and unused css.

It's really hard to analyse the unused css one by one.Please suggest any other way to know the used and unsed css in this case or any option which analyse and show the result for unused css.